# how to connect android to oracle using java socket programming

Tags: android, oracle, sockets

hello geeks as i'm new to android i'm facing a critical problem as i want my android application to connect to the external database so i just read some solutions n find out that it could be accomplished by using java socket programming...

but i have no idea how to do it....please suggest some simple and useful way to do it..

as oracle database is accessed by both the android as well as .net application..

also my requirement is that i can also access my database which will get created on my android app through sqlite database to maintain the fast access of data on my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to my [Android-Oracle Connectivity](http://androracle.blogspot.in/2012/07/java-class-as-server-for-client-with.html) blog post. That will hopefully help you. If still you have problem. Let me know about it.

and for sqlite database send me your mail id, i will send you the code that create the complete database schema on sqlite from oracle database using java socket programming at run time.

Gud luck..